# Load Balancing with 3 dedicated servers containing databases

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, ovh

I'd like to add a Load Balancing system to my 3 dedicated servers. On each server i have a docker-compose running a DB, an API server and a WebApp Server.

My goal is to add a load balancer server that dispatch connections between this 3 servers.

I'm just wondering how this could work. How to sync my 3 databases ?

I see no proper approach to this except that i should maybe use one of my 3 servers to host the database ?